# Why is this iterator returning the following values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I was reading [this article about javascript generators](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators), and I reached the following snippet:

```
function *foo(x) {
    var y = 2 * (yield (x + 1));
    var z = yield (y / 3);
    return (x + y + z);
}

var it = foo( 5 );

// note: not sending anything into `next()` here
console.log( it.next() );       // { value:6, done:false }
console.log( it.next( 12 ) );   // { value:8, done:false }
console.log( it.next( 13 ) );   // { value:42, done:true }
```

I don't understand the purpose of the first `it.next()`. After executing it, this line, shouldn't the iterator be paused at `var z = yield (y / 3)`, with y having the value of 6? Shouldn't `it.next(12)` supply the param for `yield (y / 3)`, and z be 4 after this?  I don't understand why the result of the function is not  5 + 12 + 4. It's somehow as if the first `it.next()` is ignored. Is this the case? Can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to add some logging statements to see what is going on:

```
function *foo(x) {
    console.log("starting");
    var y = 2 * (yield (x + 1));
    console.log("y", y);
    var z = yield (y / 3);
    console.log("z", z);
    return (x + y + z);
}

var it = foo( 5 );
console.log("it", it);
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next(12));
console.log(it.next(13));
```

logs

```
it {next: …}
starting
{ value:6, done:false }
y 24
{ value:8, done:false }
z 13
{ value:42, done:true }
```

As you can see, calling `foo(5)` only creates the generator object, but does not yet start it. Only the first call to `it.next()` will do that, returning the result from the first `yield`. This first call does not take any argument, because it's not accessible inside the generator function anyway.

Only the second call to `.next(12)`, here passing in a value, will then resume the generator code, with that passed-in value being the result of the `yield` expression (which is then multiplied by `2`).

Comment: Have I understood this correctly? Basically, after calling the first `it.next()`, 6 is returned to the caller, and node is suspending the function at that same yield? Thus, when calling `it.next(12)` it uses 12, instead of x+1, right?

Comment: @Geo: Exactly that is how `yield` works, yes :-) In most cases (like iterators) you don't care about the values that are passed in (or no values are passed at all), but you can do some fancy things with this. Go read on the article series you've linked in your question!

Answer (score 4):

This may help

```
function *foo(x) {
    var y = 2 * (yield (x + 1)); 
       // x = 5 (from foo(5) ) so it yields 6
       // next(12) => var y = 2 * (12) == 24
    var z = yield (y / 3);
       // from above y = 24 so yields 8
       // next(13) => var z = 13    
    return (x + y + z);
       // 5 + 24 + 13 == 42 (and done: true)
}
```